# SKSpriteNode setting color with UIColor

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, uicolor, skspritenode

I would like to set color of SKSpriteNode by Present Components Values of UIColor
By Present Components Values of UIColor, I mean:

```
(UIColor *)blackColor
(UIColor *)blueColor
etc
```

The problem is that it doesn't work:

```
SKSpriteNode *noddd = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:blackColor size:CGSizeMake(50, 50);
```

Is there any possibility to do it?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You can use UIColor with SKScene.  In your case, you have set variables but haven't set actual colors to them.

Comment: [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an SKColor instead of UIColor.

```
SKSpriteNode *noddd = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50);
```

Comment: SKColor is needed only when you are making a game for iOS as well as OSX. If you are just using iOS, UIColor will also work.

Comment: technically SKColor is merely a typedef of UIColor/NSColor depending on platform, ie SKColor and UIColor are the same class on iOS