# Is there a way to invert the colors of a SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I was wondering if it was possible to invert the colors (or adjust the hue) of a SKSpriteNode.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22430901/1498309

Answer (score 3):

You can invert the colors by applying a CIFilter with an SKEffect node. Something like this should work:

```
SKEffectNode *effectNode = [[SKEffectNode alloc] init];
effectNode.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];

SKSpriteNode *node = yourNode; // Make sure this node doesn't already have a parent
[effectNode addChild:node];
[self addChild:effectNode];
```

Note that an `SKScene` is an effect node, so this makes inverting an entire scene very easy:

```
// self is a scene here
self.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```