# How to change the color of an SKSpriteNode in touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

I am new to SpriteKit, and I'm trying to change the color of an `SKSpriteNode` inside `touchesBegan`. My attempts failed; can anyone suggest a reason as to why?

This is my code:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

   mySKSpriteNode=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-1.png"]] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
    [mySKSpriteNode setPosition:CGPointMake(150, 300)];
    mySKSpriteNode.name = @"thisIsMySprite"; // set the name for your sprite
    mySKSpriteNode.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [self addChild:mySKSpriteNode];
   }
   return self;
 }
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
   if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"thisIsMySprite"])
   {
      NSLog(@"mySKSpriteNode was touched!");
      [mySKSpriteNode setColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   }

 }
```

The `if` statement is executed, as "my mySKSpriteNode was touched!" is successfully printed upon touching the node. However, I am not able to change the color of the node. Can someone suggest a method to do so?

Comment: may be anything wrong with the syntex of changing color.

Comment: You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22430901/437146

Comment: you mean to say i have to use SKColor instead of UIColor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake, it was not changing colors because I initialized the sprite with a texture as opposed to a color.

I fixed it with the following code:

```
 mySKSpriteNode=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor]  size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct. This will allow people to see what solved the problem, and it will save the time of other users looking for unanswered questions.